# Exporting WhatsApp to PC with inline media - solutions?

Tags: backup, android, database, export, whatsapp

Not entirely sure if this is the right place to ask, but thought I'd check. I want to export a WhatsApp chat to PC from an Android device (One Plus 6T), ideally in an easily readable format with the media inline (including video, pictures, and voice notes). The chat in question was with a very close friend who passed away recently, and I am now utterly paranoid of losing the memories in the messages and want them backed up in some non-proprietary format offline. I can't simply e-mail the chat as it's huge (10,000s of messages with media) and I would prefer to have the media inline, especially as we used voice notes extensively towards the end of their terminal illness and losing the order would be a problem.

I presumed there would be software for precisely this (exporting to HTML or PDF or similar), but my googling has only revealed some software which sound my danger sense. I'm happy to purchase anything that would work, but need to check it would suit my needs, or whether there's a better workaround that other users might be able to suggest? My current backups go to google drive, so perhaps there's a way to download and interrogate these I'm unfamiliar with too.

Open to any suggestions, but preservation of the media in context is crucial, and the ability to handle long conversation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please mind: All credits of this answer go to the other Q/A [How to export/convert WhatsApp chat to PDF/Excel/HTML?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207218) on Android Stack Exchange! This is just a mere copy of its content.

As there is an answer on another Stack Exchange, but not on SuperUser, and as this question thus cannot be marked as a duplicate, here is a short summary of [How to export/convert WhatsApp chat to PDF/Excel/HTML?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207218):

1. There is a non-free extension for a Chrome browser

> It helps you save messages to your PC from WhatsApp Web. There, you
> can also check the ‘try grabbing media’ checkbox so that it will fetch
> all the media that were ever sent in a chat. It will create a ZIP
> archive with all your messages and media, easy to open and read in
> your browser. It will have the same look as WhatsApp Web. Here’s the
> link to the extension: [Backup WhatsApp Chats Chrome
> Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/backup-whatsapp-chats/gmbicfpadlmgkfhfepknbmemfhahelll).
> If it doesn't work, you can try a developer version [Backup WhatsApp
> Chats Dev version](https://chatsaver.org/files.html).

2. If you search for a free app that just exports to pdf or jpeg, refer to the comment under that answer:

> For export to Readable PDF or JPEG use [Exporter For WhatsApp-Cleaner, Saver & Direct Chat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exporterForwhatsapp.whatsappBackup.free)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: That extension worked a charm, cheers! It doesn't handle video especially well, but it keeps the conversation in some semblance of order and is well work the €3.00!