# How to export Whatsapp chats to pc - without having an unencrypted chat being moved online at any point in time?

Tags: encryption, export, data-transfer, decryption, whatsapp

It does not matter to me whether a chat is end-to-end encrypted when at the moment of saving or exporting that chat, the whole chat gets exposed in its plain text.

*The question:*

How to export Whatsapp chats directly to pc - without uploading it unencrypted anywhere else, and without exposing it unencrypted to any online tool or service while saving to pc? Any free or commercial way to achieve this is a valid answer.

*Background:*

This is a spin-off from [Exporting WhatsApp to PC with inline media - solutions?](https://superuser.com/questions/1452061/exporting-whatsapp-to-pc-with-inline-media-solutions) and from the linked [How to export/convert WhatsApp chat to PDF/Excel/HTML?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/190505/how-to-export-convert-whatsapp-chat-to-pdf-excel-html/207218#207218).

Whatsapp is end-to-end encrypted, but when I want to save a chat in whatever format - be it with inline media or not - it seems to be needed to transfer the unencrypted chat one short moment in time. Even if it just for a second, with the current tools or ways the plain text is reavealed at least once, which is one time too often.

From searching around, I get:

- Creating a backup (on my iPhone: Settings -- Chats -- Chat Backup) tells me (I would be using iPhone and iCloud then, but this question should be independent from the phone type or OS):

> that the data is not end-to-end encrypted as soon as it is uploaded to the cloud.

- Using the export function to export a chat, I can only save it to an online service (Mail, OneDrive, AirDrop...), not just to the local phone itself.
- If I use a browser plugin as mentioned in the links above, I fear that the same applies: at one moment in time, I will save the chat in plain text, and at that moment, this might work like a download from the browser which might just work online "in the browser's online streams", while I would like to be able to save the chat offline. I do not want to download, I just want to save locally what can already be seen locally when I open the chat in the browser. **Please correct me here, if I am wrong**,
  since it might be that the plugin can really directly save what is
  just on the browser screen. If I am wrong here, this plugin is already the
  answer to the question.
- I have a commercial backup recovery program "Decipher Backup Browser 14", and without wanting to advertise anything here, it usually can extract anything you want from the iPhone backup, be it voice memos, or even Safari pdf printouts, or any meta information that whatsapp generates unencrypted. It does not offer the extraction of the whatsapp chats. To me, this seems also logical, since those chats should be encrypted in the backup, and a backup extraction tool should not be able to decrypt that.
- EaseUS MobiMover seems only to be able to transfer Whatsapp from Whatsapp to Whatsapp, but not as a plain text to pc. See: https://www.easeus.com/support/mobimover/transfer-whatsapp.html:

> MobiMover is able to transfer WhatsApp messages from one iOS device to another and ensure the transferred messages on another iOS device can be used normally.